# Rcpp parameter scope propagates up?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have recently been doing a lot of Rcpp coding and have stumbled upon something that confuses me.  I was under the impression that any given function will create copies of its' specific parameters when called and then those variables would be destroyed once the function completes.  However, I have discovered when I am working with `List` types that doesn't appear to be the case.  In certain circumstances, I may need to modify list elements within different functions but want the list in the 'higher' scope to remain unchanged.  Here is a very simplified example to demonstrate the problem:

test.cpp

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
int list_length(List myList){

    // some sort of modification that could be needed locally
    for (int w=0; w < myList.size(); w++) {
        myList[w] = 13;
    }

    // return whatever metric
    return myList.size();
}

//' @export
//[[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP list_int(List myList){

  // only want the int output from function
  int out = list_length(myList);

  return(List::create(myList, 
                      wrap(out)));
}
```

test.R

```
# create simple list
myList <- as.list(seq(4))

# call Rcpp function
list_int(myList)

# output
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 13

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 13

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 13

[[1]][[4]]
[1] 13


[[2]]
[1] 4
```

As you can see, the list is modified in the scope above the function.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you miss that SEXP passes pointers.

This is pretty well-documented, we generally refer to our types as 'shallow proxy objects'.

Comment: Thank you Dirk, could you kindly direct me to such documentation.  This information alone doesn't quite help me.  I still cannot figure out how to modify the list locally within the function.  Apologies if this is simple, I am not used to programming C++.

Comment: You could search for discussions of `Rcpp::clone()` which forces a deep copy, for discussions mentioning 'Rcpp proxy object' terms, etc pp. It's been all over the mailing list in these six+ years. Last but not least, there is a [book on Rcpp](http://www.rcpp.org/book/) ...

Comment: Thank you Dirk, I will be exploring the sources more thoroughly.